# Add text in semantic zoom in window app store (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-store-apps, desktop-application, mobile-application, windows

I am new in developing windows app so i need your guidance.
I am using semantic zoom in my app. Now in that i have used one `textBlock` to display some text.

But when i scroll Mouse over it(textBlock),It also work as Zoom in zoom out like web browser does. 

I have no idea how to solve this issue. I have done enough R & D but in wain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SemanticZoom control, try adding "ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled" like this:

```
<SemanticZoom x:Name="Zoom" ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled">
    <!--OtherCode-->
</SemanticZoom>
```

Also, know that you have to do CTRL+MouseWheel to use the zoom (or the button). If that doesn't work, try doing it in your inner ListView/GridViews as well.